# Java - Strings in different languages

Tags: java, encoding

I have a String in a different language.
For example:
`String str = "наше"`
That String is passed into a function, which makes `str.substring(begin, end)` between some indexes and concatenates it to an empty string and returns that string.
Let's assume that substring is "на".

I have assertEquals in a test file that tests whether the returned value of the function is equal to "на".
But it gives me false, because the result of the function is in the form of: "��" and not "на".

How can I add support for other languages than English to the function?

```
String str = str.substring(0, 2);
String result = "";
result += str;
return result;
```

Comment: You don't need to explicitly add support for other languages.  What you've described here _should_ work; which means that there are details that you haven't told us.  Can you perhaps show us the test code, and the full code for the method that you're testing?

Comment: Likely you didn't specify the decoder correctly, so the decoding produces these placeholder characters.  You'll need to show us the full code.

Comment: yes I know, that is not the mistake tho I forgot about it while writing example

Comment: Your question shows code that makes no sense (`String str = str.substring(0, 2);`). Instead of pasting code snippets into your question, show us the complete method that is causing you problems. Help us to help you.

Comment: We need a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

Just use the call to `substring`. That works, at least in your particular case.

```
System.out.println( "наше".substring( 0 , 2 ) );
```

See that code [run at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/Z1lnsF).

> на

Your text is composed of `CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER` characters, defined within the [Cyrillic block in Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Cyrillic).

If your text still does not appear correctly, verify that your console app is set to handle text in [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoding.

If you are new to character sets and character encoding, read this surprisingly entertaining post, [*The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)*](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/).

---

Using `String#substring` does *not* work with all Unicode text. Works only with text composed of characters entirely from the [*Basic Multilingual Plane*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane), the first 64K of the 149,186 characters defined in Unicode.

To manipulate all Unicode text, you will need to learn about [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integers and the inherent complexities of digitally representing text.

```
"наше".codePoints().forEach( System.out :: println );
```

```
1085
1072
1096
1077
```

Answer (score -1):

To add support for other languages to the function, you need to make sure that the encoding of the String is properly handled.

First, check the encoding of the source file. If it is not in UTF-8 or another encoding that supports the language of the String, you may need to convert the file to the appropriate encoding.

Next, make sure that the encoding is also handled properly when the String is passed into the function. You can do this by specifying the encoding when converting the String to bytes, like this:

```
byte[] bytes = str.getBytes("UTF-8");
String substring = new String(bytes, begin, end - begin, "UTF-8");
```

Finally, when concatenating the substring to the empty string, make sure that the encoding is also handled properly:

```
result = new String(result.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8");
```

By handling the encoding properly throughout the function, you should be able to correctly handle Strings in languages other than English.